# How to choose which joined contact to use for contact image?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-touchwiz, contact-photo

Okay, I'm running a Galaxy S III with the TouchWiz ROM.

I knew how to do this in AOSP ROMs, but cannot find it in the Samsung people app.

If I have an aggregate contact with numerous joined contacts, and more than one of the joined contacts have photos, how do I specify which joined contact's photo should be the photo for the master/aggregate contact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay; I finally figured this out!

1. Go to the people app
2. Click on a contact to see the contact detail
3. Bring up the menu
4. Click `Mark as default`
5. Choose default picture, email, phone, etc.